# Armature slightly off when baking

Tags: animation, rigging, baking, rigify, gltf

When I export my actions (animations) to gltf and reuse them in three.js I noticed that some bones were incorrect. Most notably, bones that should be fixed (hands or feet on the floor) are constantly shifting slightly.

I then figured that it had to do with the baking process, and sure enough, these are the animations before, and after baking:

| Original | After baking |
| --- | --- |
| [image: original animation] | [image: animation after baking with bone shifts] |

[image: baking settings]

If I disable “clear constraints”, the resulting baked animation is correct, but I can’t export it like this as gltf.

How can I get this export working properly?

Comment: The problem is the contraints cannot be exported to gltf, so the first question would be, what kind of constraints are those? Can they be applied in some way or another so that they are not necessary for the animation? Like (this is just a dumb example) if someone uses _Copy Location_ and _Copy Rotation_ to just make an object follow another, it could also be parented. And even if parenting would not work on export, you could simply transfer movements of one object to another. Now this might not work in your case, but since we do not know what kind of constraints you are using...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thanks for your input. I’m just using the default rigify armature of the human meta rig, so all the constraints have been setup for me... I’m not sure how I can figure this out?

Comment: I'm glad you got this sorted out with an acceptable solution.  For any further people finding this question, the problem is going to depend on the actual constraints (and potentially transforms) involved.  Places that are likely problems are going to involve non-uniform scale, particularly when used with IK, but potentially with almost any constraint involving rotation or scale; stretch-to constraints; disabled "inherit scale".  Blender does things in these situations that cannot necessarily be baked to unconstrained, local transforms.

Comment: Thank you @Nathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem, by using [Game Rig Tools](https://cgdive.itch.io/game-rig-tools) which allows you to bake a separate game rig without any constraints.